# AWS ALB with lambda target through Cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-serverless

I'm trying to create an "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup" with a 'lambda' Target through my Cloudformation Template.

If I don't specify a port then I get an error that the field port is required

But if I do specify the port with target type "lambda" I get the error that the port should not be specified for target type lambda...

How can I automate through CFT or aws cli commands to create a targetgroup pointing to my lambdas ARN?

Answer (score -1):

So I would do the following using AWS cli.
Creating target group;

create file called for example target-group.json with content;

```
{
    "Name": "nameOfTagretGroup",
    "TargetType": "lambda"
}
```

and then run aws elbv2 create-target-group --cli-input-json target-group.json. Or using aws cli only;

```
aws elbv2 create-target-group --name $targetName  --target-type lambda
```

Next create a file called for example register-lambda.json with content;

```
{
    "TargetGroupArn": "ARN_OF_CREATED_TARGET_GROUP",
    "Targets": [
        {
            "Id": "Lambda_ARN",
            "AvailabilityZone": "AZ_OF_YOUR_LAMBDA"
        }
    ]
}
```

and then run;
aws elbv2 register-targets --cli-input-json register-lambda.json. Or using just using CLI input;

```
aws elbv2 register-targets --target-group-arn $target_arn --targets Id=$Lambda_ARN,AvailabilityZone=AZ_OF_YOUR_LAMBDA
```

I believe that should work for you and resolve your issues.

Comment: Thank you! will this command - aws elbv2 create-target-group --cli-input-json target-group.json     -     return just the arn of the target group created? I am thinking of doing something like this to save it as value.

targetarn=${aws elbv2 create-target-group --cli-input-json target-group.json}. 

will this work? @MC_

Comment: please refer to the docs -> [cli docs for create-target-group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/create-target-group.html). I believe you might be able able to run targetarn=$(aws elbv2 create-target-group --cli-input-json target-group.json | jq -r .TargetGroups.TargetGroupArn ). In this case your targetarn variable will contain the target group arn. However, this is using jq, you can also get the same output using purely aws cli. Hope that helps

Comment: it is not letting me use variables within the .json files I create.. example - json='{"Name": ' "\"$targetName\"" ', "TargetType": "lambda"}'    - I get error "Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: You can't have variables in your JSON file. Looks like you are not familiar with that format. In that case I would suggest to use aws elbv2 create-target-group --name $targetName  --target-type lambda.